# Using a dashicon for a custom button in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I have created a custom button for TinyMCE and I would like it to use the Twitter icon from dashicons. I am hoping to be able to do this just through the Javascript with no additional CSS. Is this possible?

Here is my current(non-working) attempt:

```
(function () {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('twitter_button_plugin', function (editor, url) {
        editor.addButton('mce_tweet_button', {
            title: 'Insert tweet',
            icon: 'dashicons dashicons-twitter',
            onclick: function() {
                ...
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your easy solution (hopefully this will help other people too):

1) add a custom class for icon, in this example "myicons"

```
(function () {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('twitter_button_plugin', function (editor, url) {
        editor.addButton('mce_tweet_button', {
            title: 'Insert tweet',
            icon: 'myicons dashicons-twitter',
            onclick: function() {
                ...
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

2) Enqueue your admin stylesheet file

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', 'URL/TO/custom_admin_style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

3) Then in your **custom_admin_style.css** file add this:

```
/**
 * TinyMCE add support for dashicons
 */
i.mce-i-myicon {
    font: 400 20px/1 dashicons;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    speak: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    margin-left: -2px;
    padding-right: 2px
}
```

Comment: CSS should have the selector "i.mce-i-myicons" (with an "s" at the end).  It wouldn't allow me to edit this because the change was under 6 characters.

Answer (score 4):

> I am hoping to be able to do this just through the Javascript with no
>   additional CSS. Is this possible?

I assume you only want to stay within `tinymce.PluginManager.add( ... )`.

Here's a JS workaround with:

```
jQuery( '.is-dashicon' ).css( 'font-family', 'dashicons' );
```

within a [*onPostRender*](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.ui/tinymce.ui.flowlayout/#postrender) event callback:

```
(function () {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('twitter_button_plugin', function (editor, url) {
        editor.addButton('mce_tweet_button', {
            title: 'Insert tweet',
            icon: 'insert-tweet is-dashicon dashicons dashicons-twitter',
            onPostRender: function () {
                jQuery( '.is-dashicon' ).css( 'font-family', 'dashicons' );
            },
            onclick: function() {
                ...
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

that will generate the tag:

```
<i class="mce-ico mce-i-insert-tweet 
          is-dashicon dashicons dashicons-twitter" style="font-family: dashicons;"></i>
```

Example:

[image: twitter]

Answer (score 1):

Using the OP code when setting icon to `'dashicons dashicons-twitter'` the editor renders the button with the following classes `'mce-ico mce-i-dashicons dashicons-twitter'`

Therefore without using jQuery what works for me is:

```
(function () {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('twitter_button_plugin', function (editor, url) {
        editor.addButton('mce_tweet_button', {
            title: 'Insert tweet',
            icon: 'dashicons dashicons-twitter',
            onPostRender: function () {
             
                elements = document.getElementsByClassName("mce-i-dashicons");
                
                for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
                    
                    elements[i].style.fontFamily = "dashicons";
                }
            }
            onclick: function() {
                ...
            }
        });
    });
})();
```